# Prevent Importing a namespace

Tags: .net, visual-studio, roslyn

Is there a way to force a compiler warning when attempting to import a namespace?

For example, the project may need a reference to **System.Data** but we would like to prevent any class or module in that project from Importing **System.Data.OleDb** and instead recommend switching to a custom data access library.

My guess is it could be possible using a custom compiler tool like **Roslyn**, but seems like something that should be doable in Visual Studio

Comment: You can make a Roslyn Analyzer.

Comment: Thanks. I saw some blog posts about Roslyn would like to get a chance to use it, but not an option right now. Good to know it can do what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) allows to setup custom rules and validation. Under `Options->Code Inspection->Custom Patterns` you can create a custom validation pattern.

Select `Add pattern` and use the forbidden namespace as the search pattern (e.g. `System.Data.OleDb`) and put your replacement in the replace pattern (e.g. `Custom.Optimized.OleDb`). You can then set the severity and `ReSharper` will suggest the change.

Obviously, this will only work if you and your team use `ReSharper`. (If not you really should)

**Update:** Answer to the question in the comments: *Do you know how Resharper manages the rules across a development team*

`Resharper` uses 3 levels of settings:

1. **Personal settings**: Those settings are bound to your user account. those settings apply to all solutions while working with your user account (Windows user account)
2. **Solution settings**: Those Settings saved locally and are applied to one specific solution
3. **Team shared**: Those settings are applied to one solution but are stored in a config file you check in, making it available for your whole team.

Using the settings level **team shared** you can share one common config file with the whole team.

In addition to that, `Resharper` offers a free command line tool, you can integrate on your build server, to enforce those rules in the automatic build.

Comment: That is good to know that Resharper can do this too. Do you know how Resharper manages the rules across a development team? I always thought it was more of a tool to check work individually not enforce warnings/errors

Comment: @mfreedm52 i've updated the answer to include your question.